# Showing that the set of non- decreasing bounded functions is compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Take the set $B=\{a\in \Bbb R^{\Bbb N}|\exists C \in \Bbb R \forall n \in \Bbb N:|a(n)|<C\}$

and the distance $d(a(n),b(n)):= \sup|a(n)-b(n)|$

Then given the subset $J:=\{a\in B| \forall n \in \Bbb N: a(n+1)\geq a(n)\}$, I want to decide if J is compact or not, given that I know it's closed ?

The theorems I think I can use :

1. continuous images of compact sets are compact.
2. any closed subset of a compact subset is closed.

Okay so from here , here is my argument:

define a function $f:[0,C] \rightarrow B$ we could just say the function is f(x)=a, where x is some value between zero and C.

clearly $[0,C]$ is compact as it is closed and bounded so by the heine borel theorem this is true.

this implies by theorem 1. that B is compact . Therefore as J is a closed subset of B , by 2. J is also compact.

Could anyone tell me if this is correct , or how I can adjust my argument ?

Comment: All constant functions are in $J$ and form a closed copy of the reals, for another argument for non-compactness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set is indeed closed, but it’s closed in $\ell^\infty$ (the normed space of bounded real sequences in the supremum norm), which is itself non-compact. So it does not show compactness at all.

In fact it is very non-compact. Define for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ the function $f_k: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f_k(n) = 0$ for $n \le k$ and $1$ for $n>k$. These $f_k$ are all bounded non-decreasing functions in your space and one can easily check that it is a discrete and closed infinite subset of it. So your set is not even countably compact.

Another simpler argument: consider all functions/sequences that are constant. These are all in $J$ and they show that $J$ is unbounded. So it cannot be compact, as compact implies boundedness in the metric.

Comment: I also noticed I made the silly mistake of defining something that isn't even a function, thats obviously where I went wrong....but I digress. You seem to use the fact that it is "discrete" as a reason as to why it is not compact, I'm afraid I'm not familiar with this term though ( it will probably show up in more advanced classes I haven't taken yet) would you be able to explain why it is not compact without using this term ?

Comment: Could you explain how you deduce from the existence of a discrete and closed infinite subset that the set is not countably compact?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven countable compactness is closed hereditary.

Comment: Isn't your set of function countable and thus countably compact?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven a countable set is Lindelöf. Not necessarily countably compact. Consider the cover by singletons which has no finite subcover.

Comment: I am so sorry, I confused countably compact with Lindelöf.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Lindelof, countably compact and discrete topology are all terms that go over my head all together, I have only learned an elementary level of metric spaces , I don't do a proper topology class until next christmas. Is there a more basic argument I can use using the Borel-lebesgue theorem or the heine borel theorem or perhaps a straight from definition theorem  to decide compactness ?

Comment: @exodius I added an even simpler argument that shows $J$ is unbounded.